# Implementing page specific java script and CSS in a ruby on rails 4 project

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

My project has two pages and each page has different javascript and CSS. I'm new to ruby on rails as well and I sort of understand the asset pipeline but not fully. There are a couple of things that I have tried so far that have not worked.

The first was creating javascript in its own file and then inside of the .html.erb file in which I wanted that javascript to load in I create a javascript link tag between `<head>` tags. Along with that I pre-compiled them in the production.rb file. This did not work and it seemed like their was still overlapping between the two javascript files.

The next solution that I tried was to implement a [jquery-readyselector plugin](https://github.com/Verba/jquery-readyselector). This involved creating a class on the body in application.html.erb like this

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
  <%= yield %>
</body>`
```

You would then include the ready selector in your application.js and finally you would scope your javascript to the page in that javascript/coffeescript file.

```
// app/assets/javascripts/alert.js.coffee

$(".pages.contact").ready ->
  alert "My example alert box."
```

This solution didn't work either. I don't know what I am doing wrong and it is probably something simple that I am overlooking because i'm a rails noob. I was wondering if someone could give me some guidance on another method to allow for page specific javascript and CSS in my ruby on rails project.

Below in my application.{js|css} files

```
application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require template
//= require form

application.css
*= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
 *= require template
 *= requre form
 *= require_tree .
```

Comment: `ready` is not an element level event. Doubt that your 2 pages constitute a significant amount of js and suspect you are over thinking this

Comment: @charlieftl It's definitely not a significant amount of JS, what is the way that you would suggest me doing it? Is it horrible to have <script> tags inside of the  page.html.erb file?

Comment: I'm not a rails dev but am simply suggesting that you probably only need one js file for both unless you expect site to grow considerably in the future. Benefit is that once loaded once it will be in browser cache for going to other page thereby reducing download time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can approach this.

By default in a Rails project your `application.js` will be included.

If you've just started your project, you can probably see it being included in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` using something like `javascript_include_tag 'application'`

Depending on how much JS you have for your page specific file, you could just require it in application.js, but if you want to serve up totally different JS, you can do something like this in the layout file mentioned above:

```
<% if content_for?(:page_script_tags) %>
  <%= yield(:page_script_tags) %>
<% else %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag('application') %>
<% end %>
```

And then in any page's HTML where you want custom JS, you can do:

```
<% content_for(:page_script_tags, javascript_include_tag('path/to/your/js/file.js') %>
```

If you just want to change your JS so that it only executes on the specific page, you could just update your JS to:

```
jQuery ->
  if ($(".pages.contact").length) 
    alert "My example alert box."
```

Let me know if this makes sense!

Comment: You can read about content_for and other layout helpers here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: It seems to make sense but what is :page_script_tags? Would that be similar to the `class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>`

Comment: Nope, it's just a random name that connects the `yield` call with the `content_for` call. You could call it anything you like.

Comment: And also, what would I do inside of my application.js file? Would I need to have require tree . or would I not want to do that because doesn't that concatenate all of the JS files together?

Comment: Yeah if you do `require_tree .` it will require all files, so it's better to just include the files that you need. `require_tree .` can be a bit dangerous since  it isn't always clear what your'e including.

Comment: I just updated the answer to include a JS only solution based on your current setup. You can check to see if the page specific CSS classes exist, then execute JS if they are present.